# Why can I update a hash map list value with a get and add function?

Tags: java

Can someone clarify why I am able to update map1 key "phone" with simply a get function to retrieve the list and then an add function to append to the list? Don't I need to use put to update the value in the map with the changes from the previous steps?

```
        HashMap<String, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> phone = new ArrayList<>();
        phone.add("201");
        map1.put("phone", phone);
        map1.get("phone").add("551"); // Confusion on how this updates the value without having to use a put function for the map
```

In this example for map2, I had to use a put function to update what was existing in the map for the key "hi".

```
        HashMap<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map2.put("hi", 0);
        map2.put("hi", map2.get("hi") + 1);
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to understand why these two different maps don't both use put to update the map values.

Comment: `map1.get("phone").add("551")` does not update the map. It updates the list, the only unusual thing is that you refer to the list through the map, instead of just `phone.add("551")`.  Both of these point to the same List object, so the effect is the same.

Comment: You should dig a little bit deeper about  Map in Java. I feel like you are not clear about the difference between Map<String, List<String>> and Map<String, Integer>

Comment: @ernest_k Okay I see so both `map1.get("phone").add("551")` and `phone.add("551")` reference the List object. As long as that object is updated, the map is able to access the changes through `map1.get("phone")`. Is this because the map with key "phone" points to the memory address of where the List object is stored since it is created with "new"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why I am able to update map1 key "phone" with simply a get function?

   `Answer:` Actually this is not like that. In this hashmap, your key is String and your value is a list of strings.

   When you pick an elment from the map using `.get` method this time it returns your value, here a list of strings.

   Now, as you get the list reference, you can do any list operation on that list. Here you add "551" to the list.

   So, now your key-value pair map looks something like this.

```
Key(String)     Value(List<String>)
----------      ------------------
phone           [201,551]
```

2. For map2, I had to use a put function to update?

   `Answer:` This time you have a map, where `key - String` and `value - Integer`.

   When you `get("hi")` it return integer 0.

   You can not perform `add, remove...` type operation in an `Integer type`.